# Undefined subroutine &main::open_quote called at /usr/local/bin/autom4te line 262

Tags: xdebug, macos-big-sur, pecl, xdebug-3, phpize

Hi I try to install xdebug via pecl on macox (Big Sur 11.5.2)
But I get error message

```
xdebug volodymyr$ pecl install xdebug
downloading xdebug-3.0.4.tgz ...
Starting to download xdebug-3.0.4.tgz (215,870 bytes)
.............................................done: 215,870 bytes
87 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20190902
Zend Module Api No:      20190902
Zend Extension Api No:   320190902
Undefined subroutine &main::open_quote called at /usr/local/bin/autom4te line 262.
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

I update perl but it did help me (I can't catch if the open_quote is a part of perl)
Also I didn't find any information in the internet that is related with open_quote function issue

I tried to install xdebug from source and get the same bug on the ./phpize step

**Resolve:**
Just reinstall autoconf automake libtool
I run
`brew reinstall autoconf automake libtool`
After that I run `brew link --force autoconf` and it resolved the trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error here comes from autom4te, not `pecl` or `./phpize`. You need to update `automake` and `autoconf`, and/or related packages.

Comment: Perfect,
I reinstall automake autoconf libtool

Run brew link --overwrite autoconf

And xdebug was installed well